# values of SIP Accept and SIP Accept-Contact

Tags: sip

I am trying to find out the range of possible values of **Accept** and **Accept-Contact** header fields, but I can't find a complete list in the RFCs. Does anyone know where they are? I often see

```
  Accept: application/sdp;level=1, application/x-private, text/html
```

but don't know all possible values. More generally, where can I find all possible values of SIP headers?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of sections in the **[SIP RFC]**[1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) are based on the **[HTTP 1.1 RFC]**[2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) in acknowledgement that the semantics of SIP and HTTP are very similar. The SIP Accept header is a good case in point. The SIP RFC section that deals with the Accept header refers to [H14.1] which translates to section 14.1 in the **HTTP 1.1** **RFC** and which goes into detail about how the Accept header can be used to specify the different types of media that are acceptable in the response.

That all being said in the real World 90% of the time the SIP response media is going to be **application/sdp**. There will be SIP requests that accept other types of response media but they are not that common.

Answer (score 1):

Bob what you are looking is MIME types.

You find some common MIME type here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

A text formation of SIP is derive from HTTP so you can refer HTTP headers also to fine possible values of other headers.

Comment: yes, but where do I find all options for all remaining headers? In the RFCs 3261, r841 etc.. they only explain the headers but never list all options available for each of them

Comment: See SIP protocol is very versatile & not stick with exact value.
For header RFC has defined syntax & not exact values.
Still for interworking with each other some values are very common & define.
But protocol not restrict you to use only that value. In one of our project where
client & server both are of ours, we have use our custom type for that in
NOTIFY request. 
If you still interested to fine possible values then 
try to take code of wireshark get SIP/HTTP dissector & you get possible values.
Because based on this values dissector take actions.

Answer (score 0):

Most headers and parameter with their corresponding RFC are listed: http://www.iana.org/assignments/sip-parameters

Comment: That tells you where to read about the header. In this case, it says that Accept is defined in RFC 3261, which as sipwiz correctly says, defers to RFC 2616, section 14.1.